# TypeError: _this2.setState is not a function, Cant bind state

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, bind, es6-class

I am getting this this error. As I am already using ES6 format, That arrow but also getting same error. And somewhat confuse that how to use bind. How can I get out of this error.

code:

```
async fetchData() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    var DEMO_TOKEN = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then((isConnected) => {
    if ( isConnected )
    {
       return fetch(`${url}`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `JWT ${DEMO_TOKEN}`,
      }
    })
       .then(
          function(response) {
              console.log(response.headers);
              console.log(response.status);
              console.log(response.url);
              if (response.status !== 200) {
                  console.log('Status Code: ' + response.status);
                  return;
              }

              response.json().then((responseData) => {
                  console.log(responseData);
                  this.setState({
                     ver: responseData.results.appversion, // getting error here
                  });
              });
          }
      )
      .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Fetch Error', err);
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear about which `this` you're trying to reference, could you do this?

`async fetchData() {
  const ctx = this`

And then reference `ctx` instead of `this`:

`ctx.setState({
  ver: responseData.results.appversion,
});`

Comment: Yehh... Thanks alot. I got it.